# How to add clear button on special input type

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, x-editable

I need to use this [x-editable plugin](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html) with the [bootstrap3 version](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/demo-bs3.html).

Like you can see in the x-editable bootstrap3 demo, we can add custom input with several fields. But in the example, each input haven't a "clear button" (like the type="text").

I've created my own custum input (with 2 input text); And I tried to add this buttons to my inputs but they don't work good. Only one input is recognize; I know why but I don't know how make it good.

part of my name.js (for example)

```
$.extend(Name.prototype, {
    /**
    Renders input from tpl

    @method render() 
    **/        
    render: function() {
       this.$input = this.$tpl.find('input');
       this.renderClear();
    },

    //render clear button
    renderClear:  function() {
       if (this.options.clear) {
            console.debug('clearBtn');

           this.$clear = $('<span class="editable-clear-x"></span>');
           this.$input.after(this.$clear)
                      .css('padding-right', 24)
                      .keyup($.proxy(function(e) {
                          //arrows, enter, tab, etc
                          if(~$.inArray(e.keyCode, [40,38,9,13,27])) {
                            return;
                          }                            

                          clearTimeout(this.t);
                          var that = this;
                          this.t = setTimeout(function() {
                            that.toggleClear(e);
                          }, 100);

                      }, this))
                      .parent().css('position', 'relative');

           this.$clear.click($.proxy(this.clear, this));
       }         
    },

    //show / hide clear button
    toggleClear: function(e) {
        if(!this.$clear) {
            return;
        }

        var len = this.$input.val().length,
            visible = this.$clear.is(':visible');

        if(len && !visible) {
            this.$clear.show();
        } 

        if(!len && visible) {
            this.$clear.hide();
        } 
    },

    clear: function() {
      console.debug('clearClick');
       this.$clear.hide();
       this.$input.val('').focus();
    },// .. other code here ..
    });
```

I probably need to use .each() before the .after() but I don't know how can I do it.

I found this renderClear (and others) method in the Text class in the main js of the plugin.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why are you proxying ?

Comment: Like I say in my question, i use the same script I found in the Text class in the bootstrap-editable.js (line 2878)

Comment: My problem is arround the reach of javascript variables and I don't know it.